# Why my project works on android but not on ios in codenameone?

Tags: java, android, ios, codenameone

I work on a big project with codenameone(i can't attach my codes because it's really big). I get android app and it's works on android devices. But recently i get ios build for this project and it's not working on ios device(just showing a white page instead of map).
My project is a map-framework that render tiles and ... on graphics(i used graphics class for drawing, transforming, writing text and more).
I used input stream for working with file because of File not supported.
I need a solution to how debug and find my problem about ios build(why tiles doesn't showed).
In fact i don'n know anything about ios and objective-c.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the logging functionality that allows inspecting issues is for pro developers (you can try the trial) its discussed in this video (mostly focused on crashes): http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-crash-protection-get-device-logs.html

From your description I would guess you created a really large mutable image (larger than screen bounds) and are drawing onto that. This would be both slow on iOS (and on newer Android devices) and might actually produce that result if the image exceeds the maximum texture size of the device.

If that is not the case you would need to explain what you are doing more precisely.

Comment: Thank you so much. for more information i porting mapsforge(http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) to codenameone somehow it's worked on android(not with good performance, it's shows something) but it's doesn't show anything just a white screen on ipad (nothing rendered)

Comment: I'm guessing you are using pretty complex transforms to implement that, this is pretty new functionality in the pipelines of both iOS and Android so we might have minor incompatibilities there. My best suggestion is trial and error, try to isolate elements to see what works/fails.